# CSS inline style not applied to thymeleaf text

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I am trying to dynamically populate the a header using thymeleaf.
I use inline style for the span element inside my header and I am able to populate it using thymeleaf.
However, the style I define inside the span element gets ignored

```
    <h1 style='margin:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt'>
    <span style='font-size:22.0pt;font-family:"Expert Sans Regular",sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:#007EB6;font-weight:normal' th:text="${subject}">
    <o:p></o:p>
    </span>
</h1>
```

[image]

I tried adding another element inside the above  element and add the th:text there but it made no difference.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: can you show the rendered html please (preferably in a snippet) - also which style does it ignore?  All of them or just the font family?

Comment: I wonder if the CSS in the style attribute is getting mucked up because of the quotes. What if you tried changing the inner double-quotes to `&quot;` ?

Comment: Also is the split `<` and `/h1>` at the end just a stackoverlow edit error or is that really in your code?

Comment: The h1 error was indeed an edit error, its' not in the code.
Changing to single quotes gives SAXParseExceptions:

SAXParseException: Element type "span" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Comment: Can you try putting the style on an "outer" `<span>` and put the `th:text` on an "inner" <span>? Something like `<span style=...><span th:text="..."></span></span>`?